# Replace current selection and all identical occurrences in a file

Tags: replace

```
This is a sample sentence.
This is a second sample sentence.
```

Let's say I select 'is a' of the first sentence. Now I want to change all occurrences of what is selected (including the selection itself) to 'is not a'. How do I do that?

Comment: @le0m You want a mapping in visual mode which replaces the visual selection with an arbitrary string ? If so you could try this: `xnoremap ,s y:<C-U>let replacement = input('Enter replacement string: ') <bar> %s/<C-R>"/\=replacement/g<CR>` (Here the mapping is `,s` but you could change it to what you want).

Answer (score 11):

You could execute the following command: `:%s/is a/is not a`
:

- Select and yank `is a` with your favorite method (visual selection and <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> with cursor on `is`, etc...)
- Enter command mode with <kbd>:</kbd>
- Begin to write your replacement command `%s/`
- Insert the text to replace with <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd>. (see **Note2**)
- Finish to write the replacement command `/is not a`
- Execute the replacement command with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note** if you have several occurrences of `is a` on same line use the `g` tag to substitute all occurrences of a same line: `:%s/is a/is not a/g`

**Note 2** When you are in insert mode <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd> allows you to choose a register and to insert its content. When you yanked your text in the first step you yanked it to the unnamed register which is accessible with <kbd>"</kbd>. So when you type <kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd> followed by <kbd>"</kbd> you're inserting the text you yanked before.

See [`:h i_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) and [`:h registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) as advised by @VanLaser for more details about registers.

See [`:h :s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s) for more informations about the search and replace function.

**Edit** I had not seen the comment of @VanLaser who basically gave the same solution, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

#### Using `gn` and `.` for quick replacements

You can use `gn` motion to make replacing matches quicker. Simply search for your text

```
/foo
```

Then change the current match with the change operator, `c`, and the `gn` motion.

```
cgnbar<esc>
```

Simply repeat this via the `.` command as many times as you wish. You can also use `n` to jump to the next match in case you want to skip any matches.

There is a nice Vimcasts episode on this topic: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)

For more help see:

```
:h gn
:h /
:h .
:h n
```

#### Aside: Tips on searching for selected text

Vim's help doc provides the following mapping under `:h visual-search`:

```
:vmap X y/<C-R>"<CR>
```

This is better than searching by hand however it does not take escaping into consideration and causes the side effect of overwriting the unnamed register. Some of this can be mitigated by using `\V` to turn on "very `'nomagic'`".

Personally I would get a [visual star](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search) plugin ([there are few out there](http://vimawesome.com/?q=star)). There is a nice Vimcast about this: [Search for the selected text](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-for-the-selected-text/). This means you can select the line visually and then press `*`.

If a plugin isn't your thing you can add the following mapping to your `vimrc` to mimic a visual star plugin:

```
xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>
```

Note: The mapping above will not work for visual-block mode.

For more help see:

```
:h visual-search
:h c_CTRL-R
:h /\V
:h /magic
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 ! With a mutiline pattern, I think the last mapping wouldn't work as expected. For example, if you have a buffer containing several groups of 2 consecutive lines `foo` and `bar`, you select one of them and copy it with `y`, and type `/<C-R>"`, instead of searching for `foo\nbar\n`, you will search for `foo^Mbar^M`, because Vim will automatically interpret `\n` as a literal carriage return whose caret notation is `^M`. At least, it seems to happen on my machine, maybe I have some wrong settings though.

Comment: what if my selection is long and I don't want to type it out again as a search pattern.  Is there really no way to operate on the selection directly?

Comment: @Xerus: Using a visual star plugin or the mapping above means you can select your text and use `*` to set the pattern. Otherwise you would need to copy the text and then paste via `<c-r>/` when searching.

Comment: This is the best answer since slice bread!